# Issue with Laravel 5.4 where collection method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have this piece of code:

```
if ($response && $response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $this->ticker = collect(collect(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true))->get('payload'));

        Log::info(json_encode($this->ticker));

        switch ($book):
            case 'btc_mxn':
                return $this->ticker->whereStrict('book', 'btc_mxn');
            case 'eth_mxn':
                return $this->ticker->whereStrict('book', 'eth_mxn');
            case 'all':    
                return $this->ticker;
            default:
                throw new ValidationHttpException(['Invalid book (9002)']);
        endswitch;
    }
```

The $response part is not important, only the $this->ticker part. This gets an API response which contains an array of objects. **The objects contain a book field which I care about.** The json looks something like this:

```
[{"high":"59999.00","last":"53021.11","created_at":"2017-05-25T23:16:44+00:00","book":"btc_mxn","volume":"1313.28966742","vwap":"55354.76622471","low":"50000.00","ask":"53998.92","bid":"53021.11"},{"high":"4699.00","last":"4102.00","created_at":"2017-05-25T23:16:44+00:00","book":"eth_mxn","volume":"7162.16835199","vwap":"4322.60134630","low":"3900.00","ask":"4102.00","bid":"4100.00"},{"high":"0.00012498","last":"0.00010700","created_at":"2017-05-25T23:16:44+00:00","book":"xrp_btc","volume":"17584.07258163","vwap":"0.00010897","low":"0.00009500","ask":"0.00011990","bid":"0.00010100"},{"high":"7.10","last":"6.05","created_at":"2017-05-25T23:16:44+00:00","book":"xrp_mxn","volume":"1015137.88406527","vwap":"6.28004670","low":"5.50","ask":"6.05","bid":"5.85"},{"high":"0.08197000","last":"0.07800000","created_at":"2017-05-25T23:16:44+00:00","book":"eth_btc","volume":"73.29999906","vwap":"0.07656212","low":"0.07250000","ask":"0.07800000","bid":"0.07600000"}]
```

The issue comes when I switch the $book. If $book = 'btc_mxn' **I get an array of objects**:

```
[
  {
    "high": "59999.00",
    "last": "53000.00",
    "created_at": "2017-05-25T23:23:29+00:00",
    "book": "btc_mxn",
    "volume": "1316.43950673",
    "vwap": "55323.60047189",
    "low": "50000.00",
    "ask": "53000.00",
    "bid": "52001.00"
  }
]
```

However, if $book = 'eth_mxn' **I get an object!**

```
{
  "1": {
    "high": "4699.00",
    "last": "4025.97",
    "created_at": "2017-05-25T23:24:18+00:00",
    "book": "eth_mxn",
    "volume": "7360.11920724",
    "vwap": "4310.48584845",
    "low": "3900.00",
    "ask": "4026.00",
    "bid": "4000.01"
  }
}
```

The same happens pretty much to any other book key which is not 'btc_mxn'.

I fix the issue by adding a call to the first() method, however this is very strange. Do someone has any idea about whats going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: This question/answer is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231077/laravel-eloquent-toarray-not-using-square-braces/36232302#36232302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book "btc_mxn" is the first book in your collection, with an index of 0. So, your `where` result looks something like:

```
[
    0 => { /* book data */ }
]
```

In json, this is a proper numerically indexed array, so it is represented as an array with one element.

However, book "eth_mxn" is the second book in your collection, with an index of 1. So, your `where` result looks something like:

```
[
    1 => { /* book data */ }
]
```

In json, this is not a properly numerically indexed array, as indexed arrays must have sequential keys starting at index 0. Since this is not a valid json array, it is represented as an object where the numeric keys are properties on the object.

If you would like this to be represented as an array, you need to rekey the resulting collection from your `where()` call. You can use the `values()` method to rekey the results:

```
case 'btc_mxn':
    return $this->ticker->whereStrict('book', 'btc_mxn')->values();
case 'eth_mxn':
    return $this->ticker->whereStrict('book', 'eth_mxn')->values();
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you very much.